# How to decorate a service from a separate, imported services.yaml?

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I work in Symfony 4.4 and I want to be able to decorate classes from outside services.yaml.
I've tried decorating from within services.yaml and it works perfectly, but the thing is I need to be able to do the same thing in another file, which I've called services_custom.yaml and imported.
My import seems to be working (btw I've also tested this by rewriting both files in PHP, with the same result). However, my class is not decorated.
I am clearly missing something but I can't figure out what.
Here is my services.yaml :

```
imports: 
  - { resource: 'services_custom.yaml'}

parameters:
  locale: 'en'
  env: '%env(APP_ENV)%'
  fallbacks: ['%locale%', 'fr']
  secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'

services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true      
    autoconfigure: true 
    public: false       
  App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php,Solutions/lib}'

  App\Controller\:
    resource: '../src/Controller'
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

  App\EventListener\RequestListener:
    autowire: true
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }

  App\EventListener\ResponseListener:
    autowire: true
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, method: onKernelResponse }

  App\EventListener\ExceptionListener:
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }

  App\Manager\SolutionManager:
    public: false
    autowire: true

  App\DataFixtures\:
    resource: '../src/DataFixtures'
    tags: ['doctrine.fixture.orm']


  # App\Custom\Solutions\woocommercecustom:
  #     decorates: App\Solutions\woocommerce
  #     # pass the old service as an argument
  #     # arguments: ['@App\Custom\Solutions\woocommercecustom.inner']
  #     decoration_priority: 5
```

And here is my services_custom.yaml :

```
services:

  _defaults:
    autowire: true      
    autoconfigure: true 
    public: false      

  App\Custom\Solutions\woocommercecustom:
      decorates: App\Solutions\woocommerce
      decoration_priority: 5
```

Comment: Imports are processed first, if your main `services.yaml` includes the same service definition, it "wins" overwriting the one from your imported file. Try adding `Custom` or  `Custom/Solutions` to the `exlude` list.

Comment: App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php,Solutions/lib,Custom}'

Comment: Thanks your solution worked !! I now need to handle the case when the custom class doesn't exist. I'm thinking with  an eventsubscriber...?

Comment: Look into [compiler passes](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html).